# Python : How to adjust row height of table in docx

Tags: python, docx

Please help me to adjust row height of table in docx.
following is code i have written to write data in docx file
But i didn't get solution to adjust row height of table.

```
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='IntenseQuote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='ListBullet'
)
document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in ordered list', style='ListNumber'
)

document.add_picture('monty-truth.png', width=Inches(1.25))

table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'
for item in recordset:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(item.qty)
    row_cells[1].text = str(item.id)
    row_cells[2].text = item.desc

document.add_page_break()

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: The solution to this is now here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194725/python-docx-table-row-height/53200144#53200144

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct api for this, but you can do it by adding direct xml for this

See code below

```
# these imports can go at the top of the file
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn


table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
for item in recordset:
    row = table.add_row() # define row and cells separately

    # accessing row xml and setting tr height
    tr = row._tr
    trPr = tr.get_or_add_trPr()
    trHeight = OxmlElement('w:trHeight')
    trHeight.set(qn('w:val'), "1000")
    trHeight.set(qn('w:hRule'), "atLeast")
    trPr.append(trHeight)

    row_cells = row.cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(item.qty)
    row_cells[1].text = str(item.id)
    row_cells[2].text = item.desc
```

Let me know it helps anyone

Comment: It helped beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped Ishaan Sharma's answer in a simple function call.  Here is another closely related utility:

```
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement, qn

def set_vert_cell_direction(cell):
    # https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/55
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.tcPr
    textDirection = OxmlElement('w:textDirection')
    textDirection.set(qn('w:val'), 'btLr')
    tcPr.append(textDirection)

def set_row_height(row):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532283/python-how-to-adjust-row-height-of-table-in-docx
    tr = row._tr
    trPr = tr.get_or_add_trPr()
    trHeight = OxmlElement('w:trHeight')
    trHeight.set(qn('w:val'), "1000")
    trHeight.set(qn('w:hRule'), "atLeast")
    trPr.append(trHeight)
```