# Python Docx Table row height

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx, row-height

So column width is done using cell width on all cells in one column ike this:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm

file = /path/to/file/
doc = Document(file)
table = doc.add_table(4,2)
for cell in table.columns[0].cells:
    cell.width = Cm(1.85)
```

however, the row height is done using rows, but I can't remember how I did it last week.

Now I managed to find a way to reference the rows in a table, but can't seem to get back to that way. It is possible to change the height by using the add_row method, but you can't create a table with no rows, so the the top row will always be the default height, which about 1.6cms.

There is a way to access paragraphs without using add_paragraph, does anyone know how to access the rows without using the add_row method because it was that that I used to set row height in a table as a default.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
row = table.rows
row.height = Cm(0.7)
```

but although this does not give an error, it also has no effect on the height.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table.rows` is a collection, in particular a sequence, so you need to access each row separately:

```
for row in table.rows:
    row.height = Cm(0.7)
```

Also check out `row.height_rule` for some related behaviors you have access to:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#row-objects

When you assign to `table.rows.height`, it just adds a `.height` instance attribute that does nothing. It's one of the side-effects of a dynamic language like Python that you encounter a mysterious behavior like this. It goes away as you gain more experience though, at least it has for me :)

Comment: Thanks Scanny, this was how I had done it last time, I'm still learning OOP so sometimes it's tricky to know what belongs to what.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional information:
The answer here is correct, but this will give a minimum row height. Using WD_ROW_HEIGHT_RULE.EXACTLY will fix the cell height to the set row height ignoring the contents of the cell, this can result in cropping of the text in an undesirable way.

`para = table.cell(0,0).add_paragrph('some text')`

SOLUTION:
add_paragraph actually adds a blank line above the text. 
Use the following instead to avoid using add_paragraph:

`table.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].text = 'some text'`

or using add_run can make it easier to also work with the text:

`run = table.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].add_run('some text')
 run.bold = True`